# CF sum of percentage column

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am having lots of trouble creating the sum of my percentage column which seems like it would be easy since its 100% when all branches are being shown. But I need to figure out the equation for the times that all branches are not shown. In the picture below each branches percentage is calculated by the number of that locations processed checklists divided by the total number of checklists. Unfortunately I can not figure out how to just "write" just adding the sum of the percentage column and displaying in into the total column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<cfset result = {} /> 
<cftry> 
    <cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
        SELECT *
        FROM cl_checklists
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery name="allLocCode" dbtype="query">
        SELECT DISTINCT trans_location, COUNT(*) AS locationCount FROM GetLocationInfo Where trans_location is not null GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
    </cfquery>
    <cfcatch type="any"> 
        <cfset result.error = CFCATCH.message > 
        <cfset result.detail = CFCATCH.detail > 
    </cfcatch> 
</cftry> 
    <cfset columnSum = ArraySum(allLocCode['locationCount'])>
<table border="1" id="Checklist_Stats">
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Percent of Total Checklists</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location Total</strong></th> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <cfloop query="allLocCode">
      <cfset thisLocationName = trim(allLocCode.trans_location) />

      <cfquery name="allLocCodeForLocationQry" dbtype="query">
          SELECT trans_location,count(*) AS locCntr FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location='#thisLocationName#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
      </cfquery>
      <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForLocationQry">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>#thisLocationName#</strong></td>
        <td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr/columnSum) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
        <td>#allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr#</td>
      </tr>
     </cfoutput>
     </cfloop>
        <cfdump var="#allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr#">
     <tr>
      <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><cfoutput>#columnSum#</cfoutput></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Unsure of how I can get the sum of this: `<td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr/columnSum) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply push the calculated percentage to an array and from there you can get the sum like this:

```
<!--- Define Array -->
<cfset checkListPercentage = arrayNew(1)>

<cfoutput query="allLocCodeForLocationQry">
  <cfset currentPercentage = allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr / columnSum * 100)>
  <cfset arrayAppend(checkListPercentage, currentPercentage)>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>#thisLocationName#</strong></td>
    <td>#numberFormat(currentPercentage, '9.99')#%</td>
    <td>#allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr#</td>
  </tr>
</cfoutput>

<!--- Get Total --->
<cfoutput>#arraySum(checkListPercentage)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to convey but simpler and more efficient. @Beginner is probably more like Expert.

Comment: this basically solves it just how do I display the 2 decimal points? can you use number format and arraysum at the same time?

Comment: @DavidBrierton yes, you can.

Comment: @DavidBrierton Also, take a look at `group` attribute of `cfloop/cfoutput` to optimize your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a somewhat similar answer before to one of these questions. This'll get you where you need to be:

---

Every time you get a percentage, you should set it as a variable and add it to a list or array. As an example for this chunk of code:

```
 <cfloop query="allLocCode">
      <cfset thisLocationName = trim(allLocCode.trans_location) />
      <cfquery name="allLocCodeForLocationQry" dbtype="query">
          SELECT trans_location,count(*) AS locCntr FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location='#thisLocationName#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
      </cfquery>

      <cfset PercentageList = "">
      <cfset thisPercentage = #NumberFormat((allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr/columnSum) * 100, '9.99')#>
      <cfset PercentageList = ListAppend(PercentageList, thisPercentage, ',')>

      <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForLocationQry">
      <tr>
        <td><strong>#thisLocationName#</strong></td>
        <td>#thisPercentage#%</td>
        <td>#allLocCodeForLocationQry.locCntr#</td>
      </tr>
     </cfoutput>
 </cfloop>
```

At the end of all your calculations, you should have a list of percentages. You can include this function to add the list together.

```
<cfscript>
function listSum(listStr)
{
  var delim = ",";
  if(ArrayLen(Arguments) GTE 2) 
    delim = Arguments[2];
  return ArraySum(ListToArray(listStr, delim));
}
</cfscript>
```

So your last row would be:

```
<tr>
  <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
  <td>#listSum(PercentageList)#%</td>
  <td><cfoutput>#columnSum#</cfoutput></td>
</tr>
```

Worth mentioning: Previously, it was pointed out to me that using Arrays and *then* converting to a List at the end of your calculations results in better performance, so that's something to keep in mind.

[ArraySum](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f13.html) is the relevant function for this.

With all the loops and queries inside other loops and queries, I just figured creating a list was a little easier.

E - unexplained downvotes are not nice.